# How to get Blend for Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, expression-blend

Microsoft clearly mentions how to start with **Blend** in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj171012.aspx) article without pointing to any versioning limitations of **Visual Studio 2013**.

I have installed ***Visual Studio 2013 Express*** and clearly there is no trace of **Blend** and surely no external link to download and install it for VS2013.

Would you please let us know with version of Visual Studio comes with Blend and preferably reference where Microsoft talks about this matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Directly form the Microsoft website

http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/

You can download Blend for Visual Studio 2013 with Visual Studio Express for Windows, Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone, and Visual Studio Professional 2013 and higher.

I'm not sure why it's so difficult to find

Comment: Well, if you know Microsoft, you know their website too. And what they are famous for are two thing. 1: The huge amount of times they change the content of their webpage and 2: How hard is it to find information on their website if it's not for Google. (And probably how messy is Internet Explorer). However their layout improved significantly in the past couple of year but I was very surprised that how on earth it's so hard to find a simple answer for this question. I appreciate the answer.

Comment: Key is that Visual Studio Express **for Desktop** is not on that list. This is the version of Express for WPF. Why this has been omitted is unclear ...

Comment: Please update this answer. Blend does *NOT* come with any free version of Visual Studio.  And indeed microsofts websites are very unclear and confusing.

Comment: But you can download blend for free by downloading Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition which is free for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

Blend does NOT come with Visual Studio 2013 Express.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615820/What-s-new-in-Blend-for-Visual-Studio-2013

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't download Blend alone without also downloading visual studio. But you get it when you install any (not 100% sure. It works with vs2015) version of visual studio community. The community version of visual studio is free so you don't have to pay for Blend. You'll also get Blend with the paid versions.

You can download the visual studio versions here: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs

After you install visual studio you can find a shortcut to your Blend in the Start Menu folder or at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Blend.exe" (if you installed visual studio in the default location)

Hope this helped you

Comment: That is surely the single most convoluted way of launching Blend that I have ever seen. It is indeed in the indicated folder, but why, oh why, is it not simply a menu item in VS, or at least a Start menu, menu item???

Comment: You can also make a shortcut on your desktop, but you still have to find the exe first, since the shortcut is not automaticly generated